Transporting Video Signal Over Optical Fiber
I have stumbled upon an issue while doing an application. In this application there is an existing multimode fiber which is installed. We will be using Sony PXW-Z90 and QuestTel's optical extenders. My application exceeds a one kilometer distance which is not supported by multimode fiber. Since changing multimode to singlemode fiber is not an option, I would like to know if there is an option that exists that doesn't require me to change the existing infrastructure to boost the optical signal.
I am truly looking forward to a good response,
John
